# Python make list copy, not reference

Tags: python

I have list of int's called `board` in python code. I wan't to know, if it was modified, so I have code

```
self.oldboard = list(self.board)
#here is board modified, if it is possible
if not self.oldboard == self.board:
    #this should execute only when board was modified
```

But `oldboard` is always equals to `board`, when I modify `board`, it modifies `oldboard`. How to make `oldboard` just copy of `board`, not reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When copying lists by the slice method (analogous to what you're currently doing):

```
new_list_copy = old_list[:]
```

you'll only get a "shallow" copy of the contents.  This isn't suitable for lists that contain lists ("nested lists").

If you're trying to copy a nested list, a Pythonic solution is to use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) from the `copy` module:

```
import copy
new_list_copy = copy.deepcopy(old_list)
```

Comment: Downvote for what? Preferred to dupe target the question?

Comment: I don't understand it either, +1 for valid method IMO.

Comment: probably because your first answer is incorrect, what do you think `list(self.board)` is doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm aware that the first option is analogous to what the OP is doing, which is why I added the explanation of "if you have nested lists."  My thinking is that the OP might see a slice copy and get confused, where the deepcopy comes with a "use this if" and a link to the doc.

Comment: `old_list[:]` is exactly the same as  `list(old_list)` so if that does not work `old_list[:]` won't work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, I'm aware.  I took your feedback and added why I mentioned slice copy to the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Better of removing it as it is more confusing than helpful, if you explained the difference between  a shallow and a deep copy  that would be a lot more useful than suggesting something exactly the same just syntactically different.

Comment: I'll change the language of why I listed it, but I'm leaving it in.  Answers meant to copy-and-paste don't teach anything.

Comment: Thanks, deepcopy works

Answer (score 0):

Integers are immutable. I would recommend you familiarize yourself with the notions of shallow and deep copy operations, which you can find in the Python Docs  [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) . 
In your case you most likely need to use `deepcopy`, as I would guess that you have several nested lists.